# Instruments not able to find a memory leak

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, instruments, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

I have this test code which i run using Profile options.
But I am not able to see any leaks

I have injected a leak but not sure why instruments is not showing a leak

```
NSMutableArray* test_leak2()
{
    int i=0;
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];

    while(i <100) {
    NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] init ];
        [arr addObject:img];
        i++;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSMutableArray *arr = test_leak2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you're in Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), you should see your allocations going up, what does the static analyzer tell you?

Comment: Did you create your project with ARC enabled? If so, ARC is inserting glue code automatically, which means that there are no leaks. Check your project settings for Automatic retain count. This maybe is the "problem". If you have not ARC enabled, add some CPU slack into main. Instruments is not gathering data in realtime, but fetching data after time intervals (like seconds). Insert "sleep(10)" before return 0. Maybe you will see the leaks.

Comment: adding sleep works, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ARC there is no leak, ARC handles the retains/releases "under the covers".

The leaks tool is not foolproof, it is a good start.

The first line of defense if the Static Analyzer, run it and fix all warnings.

Not all losses of memory are leaks, just ones that there is no pointer to. Try Heapshot Analysis, bbum has a great [tutorial here](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17). I have used Heapshot many times to great advantage, many thanks to bum.